# Get difference between 2 dates in hours minutes and seconds beyond 24 hours fails

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the following dates and I would like the difference in the format `hh:mm:ss`.

I have the following code,

```
$from = "2019-05-20 23:59";
$to = "2019-05-27 00:00";

$expiry_time = new DateTime($to);
$current_date = new DateTime($from);
$diff = $expiry_time->diff($current_date);
return $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

The above returns `00:01:00`, but I expect it to be `114:01:00`, since its 6 days (`6*24 = 114`).

I have also tried

```
$from = "2019-05-20 23:59";
$to = "2019-05-27 00:00";
$time_diff = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
return date('H:i:s', $time_diff);
```

Which also gives `00:01:00`

What am i missing? How can i convert this to show even beyond 24 hours? I have checked [get time difference in hours minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936855/get-time-difference-in-hours-minutes-and-seconds) to no avail.

Comment: The diff is 6 days 1 hour, and with your code you get the hour part, which is 1 hour... It does not convert days to hours automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `days` property of the `$diff` object, and multiply it by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day), then add the `H` format (to get the remaining hours) before concatenating the minutes and seconds.

The `H` value will never exceed 24, as the hours in a day will never be above that.

```
$from = "2019-05-20 23:59";
$to = "2019-05-27 00:00";

$expiry_time = new DateTime($to);
$current_date = new DateTime($from);
$diff = $expiry_time->diff($current_date);
return ($diff->days*24 + $diff->format("%H")).$diff->format(':%I:%S'); // 144:01:00
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/NHX4V

Comment: How  can I create an api for whatsapp like android app. Can you create a tutorial for that @Qirel

Comment: That's a very big task, and not at all related to the question here. @Pie